# Expectation of sampling integers from a reciprocal distribution without replacement

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, systems-of-equations, sampling

I have a reciprocal distribution with PDF
$$\frac{1}{x\ ln{N}}$$
I sample $k$ integers from this distribution in the range $[1,N]$ without replacement.
I need to determine the average (expected) number of each integer in $[1,N]$ in my sample.

I came across the multivariate Wallenius' noncentral hypergeometric distribution, which deals with sampling weighted colours of ball from an urn without replacement in sequence. The distribution describes the expected number of each colour $i$ as $\mu_i$ in a vector $\mathbf\mu$, which can be found by solving the following system of non-linear equations
$$\left(1-\frac{\mu_1}{m_1}\right)^\frac{1}{\omega_1}
= \left(1-\frac{\mu_2}{m_2}\right)^\frac{1}{\omega_2}
= \cdots
= \left(1-\frac{\mu_c}{m_c}\right)^\frac{1}{\omega_c}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^c \mu_i=n$$

For my use case, $c=N$, $m_i=1$, $n=k$ and $\omega_i=\frac{1}{i\ lnN}$, so the equations become
$$\left(1-\mu_1\right)^{lnN}
= \left(1-\mu_2\right)^{2\ lnN}
= \cdots
= \left(1-\mu_N\right)^{N\ lnN} \tag{1}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^N \mu_i=k \tag{2}$$
The more general Wallenius' mean is normally approximated through e.g. Newton-Raphson, so I'm hoping that the narrowing of the equations makes them directly solvable.
My work so far is as follows:

We can rewrite $(1)$ to put $\mu_i$ in terms of $\mu_j$
$$(1-\mu_i)^{i\ lnN}=(1-\mu_j)^{j\ lnN}$$
Using the identity $a^b=e^{b\ lna}$
$$e^{i\ lnN\ ln(1-\mu_i)}=e^{j\ lnN\ ln(1-\mu_j)}$$
$$i\ lnN\ ln(1-\mu_i)=j\ lnN\ ln(1-\mu_j)$$
$$ln(1-\mu_i)=\frac{j}{i}\ ln(1-\mu_j),\ \ \ N>1$$
$$\mu_i=1-(1-\mu_j)^{j/i}\tag{3}$$
We can then repeatedly substitute $(3)$ into the summation $(2)$ to obtain a formula only in terms of $\mu_i$
$$
\begin{aligned}
k&=\mu_1+\mu_2+\cdots+\mu_N\\
&=(1-(1-\mu_i)^{i/1})+(1-(1-\mu_i)^{i/2})+\cdots+(1-(1-\mu_i)^{i/N})\\
&=N-\sum_{j=1}^N (1-\mu_i)^{i/j}
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore
$$N-k=\sum_{j=1}^N (1-\mu_i)^{i/j}$$
However, I do not know how to proceed. Can this be rearranged for $\mu_i$? Am I overcomplicating things?

Comment: How do you sample integers from a continuous distribution?

Comment: If you are saying you are selecting $k$ values from $\{1,2,\cdots.N\}$ in a Wallenius'-type without-replacement method where the weight for $x$ is proportional to $\frac1{x}$, then I suspect that simulation may get you a better answer faster.

Comment: @Henry That's correct, I just need the weights to be reciprocal. By simulation, do you mean continually sampling and observing the distribution of the output? I'm afraid that is not really an option for me in the wider context of the question.

Comment: The consensus seems to be that this equation isn't directly solvable. I re-evaluated the potential for simulation and it might be feasible. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a ball can either be selected once without replacement in $k$ draws, or not at all, the expected number of times it is drawn is the probability of it being drawn.

You said in comments that you did not want to use simulation.  Just to show it is possible, and to allow you to check other calculations you may make, here is an example in R with $n=10$ for all the possible $k$s:

```
n <- 10
cases <- 10^5
set.seed(2020)
orderedsample <- function(n){unique(sample(n,250*n,p=1/(1:n),replace=TRUE))}
simdat <- replicate(cases, orderedsample(n))
count <- matrix(numeric(n^2), ncol=n, nrow=n)
for (i in 1:n){count[i,] <- table(factor(simdat[1:i,], levels=1:n))}
colnames(count) <- 1:n
rownames(count) <- paste("k=", 1:n, sep="")
count / cases
```

to give

```
           1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10
k=1  0.34305 0.17065 0.11250 0.08565 0.06820 0.05702 0.04878 0.04241 0.03788 0.03386
k=2  0.59220 0.34732 0.24146 0.18280 0.14841 0.12595 0.10735 0.09438 0.08364 0.07649
k=3  0.76348 0.51624 0.37823 0.29484 0.24177 0.20549 0.17734 0.15635 0.13899 0.12727
k=4  0.87436 0.66553 0.51715 0.41541 0.34651 0.30076 0.25883 0.22924 0.20442 0.18779
k=5  0.94059 0.78772 0.65120 0.54302 0.46255 0.40323 0.35356 0.31437 0.28348 0.26028
k=6  0.97631 0.88015 0.77102 0.66755 0.58399 0.51750 0.46126 0.41608 0.37727 0.34887
k=7  0.99167 0.94177 0.86763 0.78511 0.70843 0.64429 0.58418 0.53412 0.48830 0.45450
k=8  0.99803 0.97812 0.94039 0.88480 0.82844 0.77341 0.71887 0.67036 0.62274 0.58484
k=9  0.99976 0.99516 0.98292 0.96018 0.93124 0.89962 0.86237 0.82643 0.78881 0.75351
k=10 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000
```

This is a simulation so you should not use the later decimal places. But to illustrate how well it does, it is easy to calculate the first row theoretically, which gives

```
           1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10
k=1  0.34142 0.17071 0.11381 0.08535 0.06828 0.05690 0.04877 0.04268 0.03794 0.03414
```

Comment: Reviewing this 3+ years later, I do not know why I wrote the 4th line of code as I did.  If I was doing it now, I would have `orderedsample <- function(n){sample(n, n, replace=FALSE, prob=1/(1:n))}` though (apart from simulation noise) it may not make much difference